# auto-insert a skeleton and run a function when creating a new file

Tags: find-file, skeleton, auto-insert

`auto-insert-alist` by default matches files created in `.../bin/` directories and enables `sh-mode`.

There are [examples on the wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoInsertMode) showing how to use a skeleton to insert some text, but I want to both insert some text and enable `sh-mode`. Some other examples show using a `vector` to run multiple actions, but not with a skeleton.

I'm unsure of the syntax. This doesn't work:

```
(auto-insert-mode +1)
(setq-default auto-insert-query nil)

(define-auto-insert
  '("/bin/.*[^/]\\'" . "Shell-Script")
  ['("Default shell script: "
    "#!/bin/bash" \n \n
    > _)
   sh-mode])
```

Can you show the correct way to use vectors and skeletons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(define-auto-insert
  '("/bin/.*[^/]\\'" . "Shell-Script")
  [(lambda () (sh-mode))
   ("Default shell script: "
    "#!/bin/bash\n\n"
    > _)])
```

There are two issues here.

1. `auto-insert` **can** call functions as a part of the action, but for some reason it has to be a `lambda` form. (I wonder why it checks for `lambda` instead of calling `functionp`...)
2. The `[...]` format for creating vectors does not evaluate its contents. (See section [Vectors](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Vectors.html#Vectors) of the Emacs Lisp Manual.)

The second issue means that these two expressions have the same value:

```
(vector (lambda () (sh-mode))
        '("Default shell script: "
          "#!/bin/bash\n\n"
          \> _))

[(lambda () (sh-mode))
   ("Default shell script: "
    "#!/bin/bash\n\n"
    > _)]
```

Note that in the second expression vector elements are not quoted.

In addition to this, one needs to be careful when using `\n` at the end of a skeleton, so I added newlines to the string.

The documentation for `skeleton-insert` states:

```
Note that \n as the last element of the skeleton only inserts a
newline if not at eol.  If you want to unconditionally insert a newline
at the end of the skeleton, use "\n" instead.  Likewise with \n
as the first element when at bol.
```

Comment: Very well explained. Extremely helpful.