# Best way to make org-mode reload in-buffer settings

Tags: org-mode, auto-insert

I am using auto-insert so that I can get the usual things I use for org mode when opening a new .org file, example:

```
#+AUTHOR:   Edgar Aroutiounian
#+EMAIL:    edgar.factorial@gmail.com
#+STARTUP:  indent
#+LANGUAGE: en
#+OPTIONS:  toc:nil num:0
```

and this gets inserted into every new .org file because I added a `define-auto-insert` for .org files.

The startup in-buffer setting is important to me, unfortunately I can't get it org-mode to respect it. (Before discovering auto-insert, I used a one off function that inserted this stuff and then called org-mode-restart)

Adding a call to revert-buffer at the end of the org-mode-hook doesn't work either because for new files there is nothing to revert to, and obviously putting a org-mode-restart in the add-hook for org-mode will crap out as well.

I found that `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` will redo the in-buffer settings if the mark is placed over the `#+STARTUP: indent`, so I tried adding 
`(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c "#+STARTUP:  indent\n")` to my org-mode-hook, but that didn't work either. (Was that even a good approach?)

How can I get org-mode to reparse my in-buffer settings for all .org files?

Comment: Consider using the approach described [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3564/2355): you can make `auto-insert` evaluate arbitrary elisp code before or after inserting text.

Comment: But I'm not sure about the ordering. Doesn't auto-insert go off before org-mode gets a chance to load.

Comment: Well, you can evaluate some elisp both before **and** after inserting text: before to turn on `org-mode` and after to call `org-mode-restart`.

Comment: Any reason not to customize `org-startup-indented`, or set it locally in your org-mode hook? You could still set the options you want in the file but not really on immediately reading those options.

Comment: @glucas yay, that worked. While I would have preferred to keep it all in the auto-insert skeleton, I'll take what works now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a function for your auto-insert action, and in that function call `org-mode-restart`.

For example, this works for me:

```
(defun my/org-template ()
  (insert "#+STARTUP: indent")
  (org-mode-restart))

(define-auto-insert "\\.org$" #'my/org-template)
```

Use `(insert-file FILENAME)` to insert the contents of a template file instead of just a string.

That said, the simpler approach (as I commented earlier) would be to customize org-mode with the settings you want, so that you do not need to rely on inserting and re-reading content.