# Both set mode and insert in auto-insert-alist lambda

Tags: auto-insert

I have the following as a member of `auto-insert-alist`:

```
(("/home/robin/.local/bin/.*[^/]\\'" . "Shell-Script mode magic number")
  lambda nil
  (if
      (eq major-mode
          (default-value 'major-mode))
      (progn 
        (sh-mode)
        (insert "#! /bin/bash -peux
# "))))
```

The mode is set correctly, but the text is not inserted. And it doesn't seem to have been inserted into the wrong buffer, either, because `C-x s` says "(No files need saving)".

Comment: Related: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3564/2355